# Проверка элементов строки по условию

Tags: python, строки

Задача - "Напишите программу, которая проверяет введенную пользователем строку(string) на соответствие правилу: у строки нет ни одной гласной русской строчной буквы на каждой четной позиции. Пример подходящей строки: "пока!". Если строка подходит ,программа выводит на экран "какая хорошая строка", иначе "строка мне не нравится""
Из методички смог наскрести следующее:

```
s=input()
for i, letter in enumerate(s):
    if i%2==0:
```

дальше пробовал махинации с list и set ,но так и не смог сделать рабочий вариант.
Как это решить?

Comment: За такие названия вопрос надо сразу закрывать...

Comment: @splash58, я бы `s[1::2]` все таки сделал - потому что иначе четная позиция - это первый символ

Answer (score 1):

например можно так:

```
text = "пока"

res = all(letter not in 'аеиоуэюя' for letter in text[1::2])

print("какая хорошая строка" if res else "строка мне не нравится")
```

а вообще почему ломать голову?

в лоб задача решается просто

```
res = True

for pos in range(len(text)):
    if pos % 2 == 1 and text[pos] in 'аеиоуэюя':
        res = False
        break

if res:
    print("какая хорошая строка")
else:
    print("строка мне не нравится")
```

P.S.

говоря про четные позиция считал что счет начинается с 1 (первый символ, второй символ и т.д.), а не с 0

Comment: Спасибо большое, я чуть доработал код  под задачу и все заработало